# django query compare two models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have three models, I want to display users who apply for leave but I don't know how to accomplish that. The relationship between user to new leave is one to many and the leave balance to new leave is many to many and user to balance is one to one. I only want to display data from user and new leave.

```
 class newleave(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,default='',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leave_balance=models.ManyToManyField(Leave_Balance)
    leave=(
            ('annual','annual'),
            ('sick','sick'),

        )

    Leave_type=models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=leave,blank=False,default='')
    dp=(
        ('test','test'),
        ('test1','test1'),

    )

    department=models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=dp,blank=False,default='')
    Start_Date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=False, default=None)
    End_Date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=False, default=None)
    Total_working_days=models.FloatField(null=True, blank=False, default=None)

       def __unicode__(self):
            return  self.Leave_type


class Leave_Balance(models.Model):                                          
        user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,)
    Outstanding_balance=models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True,  default=None)
    Monthly_entitlement=models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Monthly_consumption=models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Leave_current_balance= models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Month=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="",null=True)
    Year=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')

      def __unicode__(self):
         return  self.Year
```

Comment: What do you mean by who apply for leave? Can u be more specific for the query you want?

Comment: i mean, display list of users who have applied for a leave

Comment: i only want to query the user and newleave models

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to get users that have an entry in the newleave table is

```
User.objects.filter(newleave_set__isnull=False).distinct()
```

I would suggest following [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for your code style as it allows programmers familiar with Python to quickly pick up the intentions of the programs that you write.

Class names should use the CapsWord convention - `class NewLeave` `class LeaveBalance`

Method names and instance variables should be lowercase words seperated by underscores `NewLeave.start_date` etc

Comment: Thanks i tried that but i am got the error message : Cannot resolve keyword 'newleave_is_set'

Comment: The filter is `.filter(newleave_set__isnull=False)` you may have typed it incorrectly

Comment: allleave=User.objects.filter(newleave_set__isnull=False).distinct()  i try this but i got the error as stated above. Thanks

Comment: when i try allleave=newleave.objects.select_related(), only retrieve the newleave entery not the users

Comment: @sum can you try `User.objects.filter(newleave__isnull=False)`?

Comment: i've try it, but it only retrieve the user info not newleave thanks.

Comment: Well newleave is a reverse relation from the user model, so for each user you can get all the userleave objects related to it: user.userleave_set.all()

Comment: can you please clarify i don't fully understood you saying. thanks

Comment: i try it but i got there error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'newleave_set'

Comment: user=User.objects.filter(newleave__isnull=False).distinct()
allleave=user.newleave_set.all() this throw the error above

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite straight forward but it took me a while to figure it out. I access the User models data via foreign key and Django actually took care of the joins.

views.py

def Allleaves(request):

```
allleave=NewLeave.objects.all()

return render(request,'allleave.html',locals())
```

and in the allleave.html, i access the the User info through the foreign key "user"

{% for leave in allleave%}

{{leave.user.first_name}}

{{leave.user.last_name}}

{{leave.Leave_type}}

{{leave.department}}

{%endfor%}